# How to make dynamic menu and submenu Vue 3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Im stuck and need some help on how to looping dynamic menu and submenu with Vue.Js 3.

My props.menus data send from Controller:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Menu 1",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:47.000000Z",
        "sub_menus": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "menuId": 1,
                "name": "Sub Menu 1",
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:57.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-20T03:27:57.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "menuId": 1,
                "name": "Sub Menu 2",
                "active": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-11-20T06:31:59.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-20T06:31:59.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Menu 2",
        "active": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-11-20T12:02:16.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-11-20T12:02:16.000000Z",
        "sub_menus": []
    }
]
```

And this is my controller index:

```
public function index()
    {
        Inertia::setRootView('frontend');

        $menus = Menu::with('subMenus')->where('active', 1)->get();

        return Inertia::render('Frontend/Home', [
            'menus' => $menus,
        ]);
    }
```

It should be:

```
Menu 1
    Sub Menu 1
    Sub Menu 2
Menu 2
```

This is my current code, and i wonder its still not working:

```
            <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" v-for="(menu, menuIndex) in menus" :key="menuIndex" role="button"
                id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ menu.name }}

                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" v-for="(item, subMenuIndex) in menu.sub_menus"
                    :key="subMenuIndex">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ item.name }}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But with my current code, its showing not correctly:

```
Menu 1
    Sub Menu 1
Menu 2
    Sub Menu 1
```

Thanks before

Comment: Is there an error in the console or did it show a result ?

Comment: there is no error, but i wonder the menu is not showing and also sometimes i tried, but only 1 sub menu showing @xenooooo